# IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :as-file of protocol: #'clojure.java.io/Coercions found for class: clojure.lang.Symbol

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to write a macro for use from ClojureScript to handle file I/O for a Reagent app. I get this error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :as-file of protocol: #'clojure.java.io/Coercions found for class: clojure.lang.Symbol
```

When I try to do the following:

```
(def file-string "/Users/luciano/Dropbox/projects/test/resources/blog/test.md")
(get-file file-string)
```

But I can do this just fine:

```
(get-file "/Users/luciano/Dropbox/projects/test/resources/blog/test.md")
```

This is the macro:

```
(defmacro get-file [fname]
  (slurp (io/file fname)))
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this means is you are trying to call the macro with a symbol that doesn't have a value at runtime.

```
(def my-file "foo.txt")
(def file-str (get-file my-file))
```

Will work while

```
(defn foo [s]
  (get-file s))

(foo "foo.txt")
```

will not.

Comment: That is the reason! Thank you

Comment: This answer is not correct!  get-file is a macro.  A macro manipulates literals (and returns ClojureScript forms to use in place of the macro).  This get-file macro, invoked on a string literal, can use the string and thus read the indicated file (on the build machine, at compile time); but if invoked on a symbol, then the symbol is what it receives.  The compiler doesn't process a macro's arguments before handing them to the macro. If you really want to go this way, check out the `resolve` function for what the macro might do with the symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using a macro for this.

A macro is best viewed as ***a compiler extension*** that is embedded in the source code.

All you need is a regular function, like:

```
(defn get-file 
  [fname]
  (slurp (io/file fname)))
```

As far as doing I/O from a Reagent app, I'm not sure what you're goal is.

Comment: I think the goal is to pull in some resource statically at compile time and embed the data in the resulting cljs.